# Create session in pure Node js

Tags: node.js

I know we can create session using Express JS using following,

```
express.session({  secret: 'secret' });
```

But I don't want to use any framework. Just only with Node-JS, how can we create session and maintain it?

Answer (score 1):

I do it the following way. I store the session information retrieved from the form into the redis database. You can use something like the one given to store the session information.

```
var json= JSON.parse(body.toString());

exchange.addUserSession(redisClient,json.userID,json.sessionID,function(err, response){
    console.log(response);
    res.end(response.toString());
    redisClient.quit();
});
```

And then something like this to actually store the session information in the database.

```
exports.addUserSession = function (redisClient,userId,sessionId,callback){
    //add the user and its session in appsession hash map in redis
    redisClient.hset('appsession',sessionId,userId,function(err,response){
        callback(err,response);
    });
};
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [node-sessions](https://github.com/dresende/node-sessions). I have not used it, but after skimming it's home page it looks like you don't need to use any framework.

Comment: It does only one specific thing, offers session control, thus it is a module, not a framework. It's not the glue between the modules that offers a new interface as `express` is, but it only adds the `session` functionality.

Comment: The point is to do it with pure Node.js. Using any frameworks, modules, packages, or libraries kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: OK, noted. I'll remove my answer shortly.